# How does the Darma - Smart Cushion work? Explanation of the new fiber loop ring-down spectroscopy

Tags: biophysics, fiber-optics, medical-physics

How does the [Darma - Smart cushion](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/junhao/darma-sit-smart-for-a-healthy-body-and-mind) monitor your sitting position and obtain the breathing rate, body movements, and BCG (Ballistocardiography) signals?

The creators say that they accomplish this by using some sort of fiber optic sensor technology that is embedded withing the seat.

But I don't understand how it monitors the posture of the back, neck, and hips.

So from my understanding, by reading [Dr. Junhao Hu's research paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6617192), Darma uses a new ***fiber loop ring-down spectroscopy*** for in chair monitoring, but I have no idea on how it works.